# Cakephp 3 : Unable to apply Localization in a simple text.

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am following this doc to learn localization basic. I have followed below step

I have an index.ctp file here I have added a headline

```
<h2><?= __('Popular Articles') ?></h2>
```

Now for `.pot` file I have used below command

```
bin/cake i18n extract
```

default.pot file generate well then I have moved this file to

```
src\Locale\jp\default.pot
```

Here I have found below line in default.pot

```
#: Template/Tests/index.ctp:1
msgid "Popular Articles"
msgstr ""
```

I have added `msgstr "人気の記事"`

Now in `config/bootstrap.php` I have added below code to make default language jp

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'jp');
```

Still it's giving me same output.

Comment: `.pot` files != `.po` files (or `.mo` files for that matter, which are supported too)! The former are templates. Read the whole section carefully, you seem to have missed a paragraph: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html#generating-pot-files**

Comment: After give question in stackoverflow  I always wait for your ans. You are always right. It's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the file name as `default.po`

change the folder name as `ja_JP`

and also `ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'ja_JP');`

Translation folders can either be the two letter ISO code of the language or the full locale name such as fr_FR, es_AR, da_DK which contains both the language.

**more info**: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#language-files

Comment: I have changed folder name and also add your code ini_set 
but I am getting same result :(

Comment: i have done this on bangla and i have tried your issue but its work in my end, when i set the folder name as language ISO code- `ja_JP`.

Comment: ohho, your file name was wrong. i have changed the answer.

Comment: ja_JP folder name not an issue. It also working for folder name JP/jp/. There is only one issue was file extension which mansion by ndm in comment. Please edit your question for accept your ans. I have given an up vote for now.Thank you.